# Как помечать активные ссылки навигации в роуте react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Например есть 3 роута.

1. уровень - пункт левого меню - выбрали пункт магазин (shop).
2. уровень - где ищется id товара
3. уровень - где мы продали товар с этим id

URL получается такой
http://localhost:3000/shop/521/sell

1й роутер такой

```
<NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to={m.path}>
                    {m.title}
</NavLink>
```

2 роутер

```
<li key={w.id}>
     <NavLink exact activeClassName="active-2" to= 
       {`${props.match.url}/${w.id}`}>{w.product}
    </NavLink>
```

При клике по пункту 1 уровня вложенности выставляется класс active в левом меню. 
Однако если кликаем далее по ссылкам роута во 2 и 3 уровне вложенности то из из 1го уровня пропадает класс active. И выставляется active-2 там где кликаем. 
А мне нужно чтобы у каждого уровня ссылок оставалась текущая выбранная. То есть у ссылок 1 уровня был бы класс active у активной, а у ссылок 2 уровня класс active-2.

Как это правильно сделать, чтобы не парсить url строку и не искать там соответствия. То есть есть ли нативное поведение в самом роутере реакта?